# How to retain special characters after transformation?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, special-characters, transformation

I am working on XML transformation using XSL in Java program. This is the sample XML

```
<root>
 <head>Heading goes here</head>
 <middle>Some text goes here</middle>
 <body>Body goes here &#x2019; with special characters</body>
</root>
```

The XSL has identity template and it just removes a `<middle>` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <!-- the identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<!-- template to remove middle element -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The transformation is done through Java program (Transformer class). After transformation, `&#x2019;`in the body is converted to ’ char. I want to retain the `&#x2019;` instead of ’ char. Please let me know how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In short change the Transformer class so that it preserves `&#x2019;`, if you want the long answer we'll need the Transformer class' *relevant* code.

Comment: There are other special characters just like &#x2019; . Some of them i didn't know. How to preserve all characters?

Comment: Can you please show the XSLT you are currently using? Also, can you say whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC I have added the XSLT in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the transformer will output characters as literals unless they cannot be represented in the selected output encoding. If you want to keep non-ASCII characters as character references then tell your stylesheet to use US-ASCII as the output encoding:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="US-ASCII" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

and now all non-ASCII characters will have to be serialized as references.

This won't necessarily *preserve* the input byte for byte, for example the serializer might choose to use decimal references rather than hex.

Answer (score 0):

As XSLT operates on a tree containing all characters as Unicode characters, independent of the original lexical representation, there is no way with a pure XSLT processor to preserve the representation of a character copied from input to output. You would need to use a preprocessor like LexEv http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/ to first transform character representations into markup your XSLT can operate on and transform or preserve.